# If $f$ and $g$ are algebraic functions, is $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ contained in an algebraic curve?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let's consider the following definition (I'm not an expert, so let me know if this is not the usual one!).

> *Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. A function $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be **algebraic** on $I$ if there is a nonzero polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $p(x,f(x)) = 0$, for every $x\in I$.*

Remark: Even if this is not usual, it is what I have in the situation I'm studying.

**My question is:** Given two algebraic functions $f,g$ on $I$, is there a nonzero polynomial $P\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $P(f(x),g(x))=0$ for every $x\in I$?

What I've tried: Let $p$ and $q$ be polynomials on $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $p(x,f(x))=q(x,g(x))=0$, for every $x\in I$. Write $$p(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j(y) x^j,$$ $$ q(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m b_j(y) x^j,$$ with $a_j, b_j\in \mathbb{R}[y]$ and $a_n$, $b_m$ both not identically zero.

Whithout loss of generality, suppose $m\leq n$. Then we have
$$b_m(g(x)) x^m =-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}b_j(g(x)) x^j,\quad \forall x\in I.$$

Then, multiplying the equation $0=p(x,f(x))$ by $b_m(g(x))$ as many times as needed, allows us to decrease the degree of $x$ in this equation to, at most, $m-1$. More precisely, this yields an equation of the form
$$Q(x,f(x),g(x))=0,\quad \forall x\in I,$$
for a certain polynomial $Q\in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, with degree at most $m-1$ on $x$.

Collecting again on $x$ and isolating its leading term, allows us again to decrease the degree of $x$ by multiplying the equation $q(x,g(x))=0$ by its coefficient (again, as many times as needed - and this complicates matters, since we're talking about powering polynomials).

So eventually, we're going to have an equation "free of $x$", i.e. $P(f(x),g(x))=0$, for some $P\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

> **Example:** Consider $n=2$, $m=n-1$. For the sake of simplicity, let's write $a_j(f(x))$ and $b_j(g(x))$ just as $a_j$, $b_j$. Then we have $$a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0,$$ $$b_1x=-b_0.$$
> Multiplying the first equation by $b_1^2$, we get the relation $$a_2b_0^2-a_1b_0b_1+a_0b_1^2=0.$$
> The case $n=3$, $m=n-1$ will require two steps and yields a considerably more complicated relation...

This seems a very promising algorithm, at least in theory (although computationally expensive). **But is there any hope to pose conditions on $f$ and $g$ in order to guarantee that $P$ is nonzero? Actually, what $P\equiv 0$ would mean for $f$ and $g$? (this seems very unlikely in general).**

Comment: I feel like the answer is "yes" and that a concise proof is available using transcendence degrees of field extensions; but I'm not familiar enough to write a proper argument to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and we don't necessarily have to construct an explicit $P$. If $f$ is constant, say equal to $r\in\Bbb R$, then $P=x-r$ suffices. Now suppose $f,g$ are nonconstant. Consider the tower of fields $\Bbb R(f)\subset \Bbb R(f,g)\subset\Bbb R(x)$. As $\Bbb R(f)\subset\Bbb R(x)$ is algebraic, the extension $\Bbb R(f)\subset\Bbb R(f,g)$ is algebraic, so there is a nonzero polynomial in $\Bbb R(f)[t]$ satisfied by $g$. Clearing denominators, we obtain a nonzero polynomial $P$ which vanishes on $f$ and $g$.

There are other ways to see this, too. One is to consider the ideal $J=(p(x,y),q(x,z))\subset\Bbb R[x,y,z]$ and note that $J\cap \Bbb R[y,z]$ will contain a $P$ if it's nonzero. But $f,g$ nonconstant imply $p,q$ nonzero imply $J$ of height two, so the intersection  $J\cap \Bbb R[y,z]$ cannot be zero (algebro-geometrically, this is the statement that an [algebraic] curve in 3-space cannot project down to cover the whole plane).

If you do want to construct an explicit $P$, one way to do this is to write $p=p'd$ and $q=q'd$ for $d$ the GCD of $p,q$, then take the resultant of $p$ and $q'$ - this is guaranteed to not vanish as they're coprime, and it can actually (kind of) be calculated.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. By the way, the relation in my example is precisely the resultant of the polynomials! I've checked it for degree three too. So, somehow it seems equivalent to my given algorithm, but much more organized, straightforwardly computable and full of properties.